# MS Access Insert where not exists

Tags: ms-access, insert, conditional-statements, where-clause, exists

I have the following table:

```
+-----------+--------+
| FirstName | Active |
+-----------+--------+
| Rob       | TRUE   |
| Jason     | TRUE   |
| Mike      | FALSE  |
+-----------+--------+
```

I would like to insert 'John' (with Active=True) only if an entry for John doesn't exist already `where Active=True.` I try the following:

```
insert into testTable (FirstName, Active) values ('John',True) where not exists (select 1 from testTable where FirstName='John' and Active=True)
```

but i get 
'Query input must contain at least one table or query'.

Can anybody help with what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm sorry about the format of the table. I am still not sure how to paste a table onto here (any help there would also be appreciated..)

Answer (score 7):

You can't combine `Values` with a `WHERE` clause. You need to use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` instead.

Since you don't want to insert values from a table, you need to use a dummy table like this (assuming that `testTable` has an index):

```
INSERT INTO testTable (FirstName, Active) 
SELECT 'John', True
FROM (SELECT MIN(id) FROM testTable)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from testTable where FirstName='John' and Active=True)
```

`SELECT MIN(id) FROM testTable` always returns a dummy table even in case `testTable` is empty.

Comment: Thanks, this works if I am executing directly in Access, but given I am generating the input query via a VB script and executing it from there with  and ("ADODB.Connection") (Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0), I get an 'Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'MSysObjects'. Any other ideas? thanks a lot

Comment: Well, use `testTable` instead of `MSysObjects` as your dummy table if you're sure that always contains records, or create your own dummy table.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the field already exist in the table  so I changed it from an INSERT to an UPDATE query and it worked.